# REST Webservice with Maven works in Tomcat but not in Weblogic 12c - Eclipse

Tags: weblogic12c

REST Webservice with Maven works in Tomcat but not in Weblogic 12c - Eclipse Oxygen, Please let me know in case of any changes on Weblogic.

In Weblogic - When i hit the URL browser i am getting "Http 405 method not allowed"

http://localhost:7001/RestServices/services/search/

I am stuck up for a long in this issue. Please help.

Comment: Probably you are sending GET method, and expecting a different one (POST?)

Comment: I tried POST method as well. Still the same issue. But it works fine in Tomcat. I've already done Weblogic setup in eclipse. Only facing issue in Weblogic. Do i need to configure any weblogic level settings

Comment: the 405 could be for several reasons, one of those is the expected method. Could you show code and configuration.